# Using VBA to click a button with no ID

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to navigate to a website and then extract some data. So far I've been able to navigate to the website and, but I can't figure out how to click on the buttons I need. Based on the research I've done, using `querySelector` is a much better option than using `getElements`.

When I inspect the button I'm trying to click on it brings me to the following line in IE's DOM explorer

```
<INPUT width="80" class= "button" onclick= "updateSummary();"  type= "button" value="Apply Filters"></input>
```

Based on my research, I've got the following:
. 
. 
.

```
Ie.document.queryselector("input[value=Apply Filters]") (0).click
```

But I get a

> runtime '438' object doesn't support this property or method.

I'd also like to be able to click on an "Export to CSV" button, and the html code has an href component and a source = "dynamically changing code based on the day" component.

Would it be possible to click on the export to to CSV button and either open the file or save it in a folder?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: may not be applicable, but strictly speaking, that's not valid HTML for the input definition.

Comment: `document.queryselector` returns either a single element or null if there's no match.  So try dropping the `(0)`

Comment: Please ask a new question and include the relevant html for your second question.

Comment: If the object of clicking the button is to run the updateSummary() script, have you tried the [execScript method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms536420(v=vs.94)) to run it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. As mentioned in comments, drop the zero as you are not dealing with a nodeList. `querySelector` returns a single node which is the first match for the specified selector, or null.
2. You cannot pass a selector for attribute value that contains spaces without enclosing within ''

   ```
   ie.document.querySelector("[value='Apply Filters']")
   ```

You could also use:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[onclick='updateSummary();']")
```